# Twitter API 1.1 collections show 403/220

Tags: api, twitter, collections

I can't access this particular Twitter API endpoint:

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/collections/show.json?id=576828964162965504`

(with any ID I tried). The request returns an error with the message "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource" and code "220".

The App-only authentication Bearer Token I'm using for the request is exactly the same as for my requests to `/search/tweets.json`, `/statuses/user_timeline/show.json`, `/statuses/show.json` and `/users/show.json`, all of which work just fine. Also the collection is public, so App-only authentication should suffice, I'm thinking.

I'm somehow sure that I'm missing something here, but can't find it anywhere in the official API docs, nor on StackOverflow, nor on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Twitter API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/curate-a-collection/api-reference/get-collections-show), collections/show requires a user context - so app-only authentication will not work in this case.

Additionally, collection IDs are usually in the form "custom-756140390927872000" or similar. You can get the list of collection IDs from a user by hitting the collections/list?screen_name=handle query.

Comment: Oh, there it is, in the little table. That's what I've been looking for, thanks!